# Would "development of" suggest exclusive performance?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

In a CV, "development of a ... software" is an appealing, short expression.
But does it suggest that the author has accomplished the development on their own?

Please advise, I may have to fall back to things like "contributed to" and "participated in" then. I would like to keep the size short (struggling to fit it into 1 page), but the content correct. Have I missed anything?

Comment: I've done a lot of work with CVs and resumes. Although you will rarely be asked about any one thing, you might! You should write it as it happened. Pick fewer things to put on your CV if you're struggling to shorten, preferential to things you had the most responsibility for. If it's a large program, pick the part you were responsible for, even if it's technical. If it was a small group I'd use the word *collaborated*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "development of ... software" does suggest exclusive performance.  That being said, typically in any software development team effort, individuals DO develop certain modules, units, pieces of the platform, etc. on their own.  Therefore, you can genuinely use "development of ..." on your own CV if you creatively and accurately limit what comes after the words "development of ..." to what you did.  Examples:  "development of critical components of the user interface to widely used CAD software" or, "development of core components of upgraded operating system platform."

I have consulted with many persons over thirty years in resume and CV writing; my biggest piece of advice in the word choices task is to pick the words that correlate to the job you are seeking, rather than to the job you left or are leaving and rather than to your sense of how long or short the wording should be.  So - if the job you want is more in the project management or teamwork arena, as opposed to the IT or programming/individual engineering arena, then "development of ... software" are not as effective word choices as "successful collaboration with ..." or "lead facilitation ..."  ...

Good luck!